# UILabel not showing entire text

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collection view cell which has a button and a label. So whenever I add items on collection view, multiple pairs of button and label are displayed i.e. button1-label1, followed by button2-label2 after some space between label1 and button2.

Whenever I assign some text to the label it just shows first 2 letters of the text on the label. I tried increasing the width of the label, calling 'sizeToFit()' and 'layoutIfNeeded()' after text is set on the label, but still there was no change.

What am I doing wrong?

**Label frame is** - (34.0, 10.0, 100.0, 16.0)

**Collection view layout API's:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 25)
}
```

***Below are the label settings***:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

tech_human,How have you laid out the UI, is the button next to the label?

If yes, place the button below the label and have the Trailing Alignment constraint to be a `Less than or Equal to` Relation.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time checking the frame.width value of everything and noticed that even though frame of the label was bigger, frame.width of the actual collection view cell was smaller than the frame.width of the label. Below is the solution:

```
collectionViewCell.frame.size.width = collectionViewCell.label.frame.width + collectionViewCell.button.frame.width + 25
```

25 in the above solution stands for 'minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt' which I changed from 100 to 25.